# Uploading Large Files

Tags: file-uploads, channel-files

Currently working on a site that will be making audio files available to their membership.  My Resource channel has a Channel Files field ("Audio") to upload such files.  Originally I was going to upload these files to a folder above root for additional security.  When that didn't work, I changed it to a regular folder within the site.  That still doesn't work.

When I try to upload a large MP3 file (~ 20-25MB), it goes all the way through the process, then I get an error that says

`Upload request failed, no HTTP 200 Return Code! OPEN ERROR`

When I open the error, I simply get a message that says

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

I tried skipping Channel Files and tried to upload the same file through File Manager, and also got the "Internal Server Error" message.

This is on a dedicated server, so I have full access to everything.  My php.ini settings show

```
asp_tags = Off
include_path = ".:"
ignore_repeated_source = Off
variables_order = "GPCS"
track_errors = Off
output_buffering = 4096
auto_globals_jit = On
doc_root = 
log_errors = On
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
auto_append_file = 
disable_classes = 
display_startup_errors = Off
user_dir = 
enable_dl = Off
register_argc_argv = Off
display_errors = Off
open_basedir = none
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode_exec_dir = 
default_socket_timeout = 60
html_errors = Off
register_globals = Off
unserialize_callback_func = 
y2k_compliance = On
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
expose_php = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
post_max_size = 150M
report_memleaks = On
engine = On
memory_limit = 128M
short_open_tag = On
max_execution_time = 800
safe_mode_include_dir = 
serialize_precision = 100
precision = 14
upload_max_filesize = 150M
register_long_arrays = Off
safe_mode = off
zlib.output_compression = Off
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
request_order = "GP"
default_mimetype = "text/html"
allow_url_include = Off
disable_functions = 
file_uploads = On
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
max_input_time = 800
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
safe_mode_gid = Off
auto_prepend_file = 
implicit_flush = Off
allow_url_fopen = On
```

I tested it with uploading a 5MB MP3 file and some smaller .txt and .wav files.

Anything obvious that I'm missing or could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Your memory limit is set lower then your upload limit. Not sure if that would affect anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While I'm on a dedicated server, my changes don't seem to be taking effect.  So I'm working with my host to change it and see if that makes a difference.  Seems like it's always one step forward and two steps back!  :(

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to a persistent support team at my host (Codero), they were able to track down the issue.  They said since I was running PHP through FastCGI, it was an Apache error that was causing the problem.  They made changes to the domainvirtualhost.php file and I am now able to upload 35MB + files.